# Refresh page when directory content changes

Tags: php, javascript

I am working on an online jQuery slideshow for showing the latest scores for a local sport community. The slides are images, made from a Powerpoint presentation, which are automatically synced with a directory on my Centos6 server using the Windows program Autover.

For a good user experience it would be great when the page is refreshed when the images are updated (or show some text that the scores are updated and let the user refresh). I could set a meta refresh, for refreshing the page every 10 minutes but thats not an ideal solution.

Browsing other topics I found out that it is not possible to monitor a server directory using only Javascript.

My idea is now to make a php script to which returns true (changed) or false (not changed), and call this script from the slideshow webpage every 5 minutes using javascript.

For the php script I read some topics using these solutions:

- Inotify-tools (which is not installed by default on Centos)
- FAM (could be outdated?)
- Making a md5 hash of the directory, and compare this with a previous hash.

Which of the solutions above is the best way to go? Could someone provide me with an php example? Unfortunately my php skills are not so good.

Comment: Hashes and FAM etc etc is not required, just make an ajax call, as simple as that

Comment: Check for update and then reload page. Not very good idea. You can call script for load list of files in folder. And then just add it to your slideshow.

Comment: Up there there is all you read somewhere else. Now, what about telling us what is your current setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the PHP function **stat**, you can get the information of the directory.

The document is here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php

For example you can get the modification time and directory size as below:

**dir_stat.php**

```
<?php
$stat = stat('\path\images');
echo 'time: ' . $stat['mtime']; /* time of last modification (Unix timestamp) */
echo 'size: ' . $stat['size'];  /* size in bytes */
?>
```

And on the client side, you can retrieve the directory information and compare them at  fixed intervals. 
The example code might goes like below with jQuery.

```
<script language="javascript">

var myVar=setInterval(function(){chekUpdate()},5*60*1000); // at 5 minutes intervals
var stat_old = "";
function chekUpdate()
{
    $("#stat").load("/path/to/dir_stat.php",function(){
        var stat_new = $("#stat").html();
        if((stat_old != "") && (stat_old != stat_new)){
            refreshSlideShow();
        }
        stat_old = stat_new;
    });
}
function refreshSlideShow()
{
    // you can refresh your slideshow here.
}
</script>
<body>
<div id="stat">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. I was working on a solution (see below). Since the image names in my case are always the same I used filemtime. This solution is more general and therefore better. Thanks

Comment: Thank you "naota". Your code helped my a lot! I had a similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928102/php-automatically-refresh-page-if-the-content-of-a-specific-file-has-changed).

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that you make an asynchronous request to the server every N minutes, and the server returns the directory contents (for example filenames in a JSON array): if they changed since the last update, you modify your DOM accordingly. So you need only to implement a PHP service to list the contents of the target directory and return the serialized filenames list. No hashes and no inotify needed.

Note that this design is unnecessary heavy on resources usage (mainly bandwidth, but also CPU because of the high number of incoming requests), because if the directory is not changed for 365 days, still a client issues lots of useless requests. The resource usage can obviously be optimized by introducing so-called server push: your client may maintain a long connection to the server, and, when something change, **the server itself** delivers the fresh data to all connected clients.

Unfortunately, server-sent events are not usually developed in PHP because of poor environment support, so you'll have to switch to some other technology (google for comet servers, or websocket capable servers), and that's why inotify will never come to play with PHP (even if it has a PHP wrapper).

Comment: The problem is that the image names are always the same Slide1.JPG, Slide2.JPG etc. They are overwritten every time the scores are update.

It is a low traffic site btw.

Comment: I am reading into server-sent events now. I fear however this is a bit overkill for this small, low traffic site.

Answer (score 0):

no ajax calls needed just update src and pass a random query string to force browser to re-look for images on server and update them on browser window

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
        function updateImages()
        {
             document.getElementById('img_slide1_element_id').src = 'Slide1.JPG?' + Math.random();
             document.getElementById('img_slide2_element_id').src = 'Slide2.JPG?' + Math.random();
                 window.setTimeout(function(){
                   updateImages();
                 }, 60000 * 10);
        }
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            updateImages();
        }, 60000 * 10);
    </script>
```

Comment: How it will help for new files in folder?

Comment: see his comment on other answer he knows file names they are overwritten new files are added but they overwrite existing files

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt:

```
<?php

$filename = "plaatjes/Dia1.JPG";
$myFile = "plaatjes/timestamp";

if (file_exists($myFile)) {
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
    $theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
    fclose($fh);
}
else {
    $theData = 'x'; }

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    $timestamp = date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename));

    if ($theData === $timestamp) {
    echo "True";
    }
    else {
            echo "False";
            $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
            fwrite($fh, $timestamp);
            fclose($fh);
    }
}

?>
```