# PHP automatically refresh page if the content of a specific file has changed

Tags: php

I'm trying to determine if the content of a specific file was changed and than automatically refresh a php page that displays a message.

I want to make this a single php page that after loading, can check if "test.txt" was changed.

If someone added or deleted data from the "test.txt", i need to automatically refresh the div in which the "message.php" is displayed.

Basically I need to make "index.php" check if "test.txt" was changed. If yes than I have to automatically refresh the div in which the "message.php" is displayed or at least refresh the entire "index.php" 
Here is what I am using:

-a text file called "test.txt" in which text is added or deleted

-a "check_md5.php" that check if the file was changed:

```
<?php
function file_was_changed($file_to_check,$interval_check_md5)
{
    //intializez md5 variables to  0
    $valoare1_md5=$valoare2_md5=0;

    //detect first md5 value
    $valoare1_md5=(md5_file($file_to_check));
    echo '<p>FILE "'.$file_to_check.'" => MD5 1 ='.$valoare1_md5.'</p>'.PHP_EOL;

    //wait for the given interval
    sleep($interval_check_md5);

    //detect second MD5 value
    $valoare2_md5=(md5_file($file_to_check));
    echo '<p>FILE "'.$file_to_check.'" => MD5 2 ='.$valoare2_md5.'</p>'.PHP_EOL;

    //compare MD5 values and determine and set boolean accordingly
    if ($valoare1_md5==$valoare2_md5) 
    {
        return false;
        echo 'FILE WAS NOT CHANGED';
    } 
    else 
    {
        return true;
        echo 'FILE WAS CHANGED';
    };
}

?>

<?php

$file_changed=(file_was_changed('test.txt',1));
if ($file_changed==true)
{
    echo 'FILE WAS MODIFIED';
} 
else 
{
    echo 'FILE IS UNCHANGED';
};

?>
```

-a "message.php" that displays the message "HELLO":

```
<?php
    echo 'HELLO';
?>
```

-a "index.php" that contains 2 divs in which "check_md5.php" and "message.php" are loaded:

```
<html>


<style>
.md5_status, .display {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.md5_status {
  top: 0;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: pink;  
 /* overflow:scroll; */
}

.display {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 85%;
  background-color: #ddd;    
}
</style>

<body>
    <div id="links" class="md5_status">
    <?php //include("verificare_md5.php"); ?>
    <?php include("check_md5.php"); ?>
    </div>

    <div id="contents" class="display">  
    <?php //include("extrage_date_din_xml.php"); ?>
    <?php include("message.php"); ?>
    </div>
</body>
<html>
```

How can I make this? Thank you for taking the time to read my entire problem.

Comment: You will need to use AJAX for this.

Comment: Be careful, in your file_was_changed function, you try to echo something after the return of the function. Theses messages will never appear.

Comment: @Nenroz: Thank you for the observation. I will change this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problems can be found here: [Refresh page when directory content changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040064/refresh-page-when-directory-content-changes/14040807#14040807)
I've adapted the code and it works perfectly!
Thank you Noata!

I use an index page to display 2 divs. The first div holds infomation regarding the file timestamp that are gathered from the "check_file_stat.php" using stat php "stat" function.The second div loads the data from the "message.php".

-The content of "index.php":

```
<script language="javascript">

//var myVar=setInterval(function(){chekUpdate()},5*60*1000); // at 5 minutes intervals
var myVar=setInterval(function(){chekUpdate()},1000);
var stat_old = "";
function chekUpdate()
{
    $("#status_fisier").load("check_file_stat.php",function(){
        var stat_new = $("#status_fisier").html();
        if((stat_old != "") && (stat_old != stat_new)){
            refreshSlideShow();
        }
        stat_old = stat_new;
    });
}
function refreshSlideShow()
{
    // you can refresh your slideshow here.

    location.reload(); 

}
</script>


<body>



<style>
#status_fisier, #display_ticker {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#status_fisier {
  top: 0;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: pink;  
 /* overflow:scroll; */
}

#display_ticker {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: #ddd;    
}
</style>

<div id="status_fisier">

</div>
<div id="display_ticker">
<?php include("message.php"); ?>
</div>

</body>
```

-The content of "check_file_stat.php":

```
<?php
$locatie_fisier_de_verificat='test_fisier.txt';
/*

The stat() function returns information about a file.

This function returns an array with the following elements:

    [0] or [dev] - Device number
    [1] or [ino] - Inode number
    [2] or [mode] - Inode protection mode
    [3] or [nlink] - Number of links
    [4] or [uid] - User ID of owner
    [5] or [gid] - Group ID of owner
    [6] or [rdev] - Inode device type
    [7] or [size] - Size in bytes
    [8] or [atime] - Last access (as Unix timestamp)
    [9] or [mtime] - Last modified (as Unix timestamp)
    [10] or [ctime] - Last inode change (as Unix timestamp)
    [11] or [blksize] - Blocksize of filesystem IO (if supported)
    [12] or [blocks] - Number of blocks allocated


*/
$stat = stat($locatie_fisier_de_verificat);
echo '<p>Verificare stare fisier: "'.$locatie_fisier_de_verificat.'"</p>';
echo '<p>Timpul ultimei modificari (UNIX Timestamp): ' . $stat['mtime'] . "</p>"; /* time of last modification (Unix timestamp) */
echo '<p>Dimensiune in bytes: ' . $stat['size'] . "</p>";  /* size in bytes */
?>
```

-Content of "message.php":

```
<?php
    echo 'HELLO';
?>
```

Again, a big THANK YOU and an Upvote for the solution posted by Noata here: [Refresh page when directory content changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040064/refresh-page-when-directory-content-changes/14040807#14040807)